# ggannimate - basing transition sequence on quarter

Tags: r, gganimate

```r
library(lubridate)
library(gganimate)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data("crime")

#creating test data and getting quarter
TestData <- crime %>%
  mutate(Quarter_year = floor_date(time, unit = 'quarter'),
         Quarter_year = as.Date(Quarter_year)) %>%
  group_by(Quarter_year) %>%
  tally() 

#Creating a simple bar graph
Graph <- TestData %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Quarter_year, y = n))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()+
  theme_minimal()

Animated_Graph <- Graph+
  transition_time(Quarter_year)+
  ggtitle("Test: {frame_time}")

animate(Animated_Graph)
```

Using the great package gganimate I want to set my frame time based on a dates quarter.

However, when I pass through a transition time, the animation creates a frame for each day between quarters, even though they are not in the dataset

```
transition_time(Quarter_year)+
  ggtitle("Test: {frame_time}")
```

Is it possible to keep transition using only dates that appear in the dataset?

Thanks.